# Help with associations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

Let me describe what i want to do:
There is a Match model, which should have info about what players and what clans attended in it, with division of home players and clan and away players and clan.
That is pretty easy, but there is another model: Summoner. In each match every player has different summoner and I need to do something like this: `Match.find(1).players_home.find(1).Summoner.name` to extract which summoner played player 1 in home team.
The point is: each player in each match can play with different summoner.
I hope I described it clearly.
Regards.

Comment: So what is the question? Do you have some code to show us?

Comment: The question is how to set up associations and models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure about all your specifications regarding when an association is one or several, but I think something like this could be it:

```
class Match
  has_many :participations
  has_many :players, :through => :participations
end

class Participation
  belongs_to :match
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :summoner

  # also a team attribute to store either "home" or "away"
  scope :home, where(:team => "home")
  scope :away, where(:team => "away")
end

class Player
  belongs_to :clan
  has_many :participations
  has_many :matches, :through => :participations
end

class Summoner
  has_many :participations
end
```

In this setup every match has several participations. Every participation belongs to the player that is participating and also belongs to a summoner for that player and match. It can then be utilized perhaps like this:

In Controller

```
@match = Match.find(1)
@home_participations = @match.participations.home
@away_participations = @match.participations.away
```

In View

```
<h1>Home Players</h1>
<% @home_participations.each do |p| %>
  <p>Player: <%= p.player.name %>, Summoned by: <%= p.summoner.name %></p>
<% end %>
```

I hope this was at least somewhat what you where going for. Let me know if you are looking for something else.